# Redis Sentinel Using Redis Stack Server

Tags: redis, sentinel

I am trying to add sentinel in Redis stack server but not able to achieve. After deployment everything is working properly until I delete the master node . After deleting the master node they aren't electing any master node among themselves.Also , new pod is created automatically but as a slave. I think the issue is they are't able to elect new master and make required changes.The sentinel works completely fine when used with Redis.
Can anyone help me with same?

[Used this GitHub for Reference](https://github.com/marcel-dempers/docker-development-youtube-series/tree/master/storage/redis/kubernetes)But using image **redis/redis-stack-server:6.2.6-v7**
[Before deleting the master node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5G2z.png)
[After Deleting the master nodes showing slaves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkjCY.png)